# Need a way to move a form with another form

Tags: vb.net, forms

So currently I have this [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoF1L.png)
,The part under the pink box is transparent, so the orange reddish thing in the box is my wallpaper.

And what I want to do is have another form like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMyvv.png) (where the red box is the other form). And whenever I move form 1, the red form also stays relative to form 1. I also need the red form to follow form 1 when scrolling up and down on form 1.

Is this possible? If so how? Should I get the resolution of the current monitor and do math, or what?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This

At Form1_Load Event

```
 'Set form2 TopLevel property to False so you can add it as a child form to form1
    Form2.TopLevel = False
    Form2.Parent = Me
    Form2.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
 'set form2 Location.X,Location.Y, Width and Height. All that inside form1 as the upper left point of it is (0,0) related to form2
    Form2.SetBounds(50, 50, 100, 100)
    Form2.Show()
```

Comment: when scrolling will this stick to the point on the form? Should I make the panel on the form a parent? For example form2.parent = Me.Panel1? Would that work? -- Also thanks for taking the time to type an answer <3 I suck at asking questions, so at least someone takes the time to see beyond that. :)

Comment: You are Welcome. And Yes it will work when scrolling and you can use a panel as a parent

Comment: O.o im not home, so i cant test it, but im thinking, will it show when scrolling if it isnt under the form? Like i dont want the user to be scrolling and the other form shows while they are scrolling from the bottom?

Comment: It will move vertically or horizontally inside its parent when the user scrolling the parent form.

Comment: It works perfectly man, Im marking this as solved. Btw how do I make the program end? It seems to keep that form open after closing form1?

Comment: Fixed, just added an OnForm Close event to close that to, thanks so much man!